# Regex - match words which only consists of certain characters and certain char is repeated certain times

Tags: regex

I have words database containing of 300 000+ words

I want to match words which length is known (7 for example) and it contains 
only certain characters and some of them can be repeated certain times but not all of them

## for example

I have `a,p,p,l,e,r,t,h,o`  chars and I want to find words which length is 5

so, it can match

`apple`
`earth`

but not

`hello` because `l` is specified more than one time

## My attempts

```
 ^([a,p,p,l,e,r,t,h,o]{1}) # capture first char 

 (!/1 [a,p,p,l,e,r,t,h,o]{1}) # capture second char but without firstly captured symbol

 (!/1 !/2 [a,p,p,l,e,r,t,h,o]{1}) # capture third char but without first and second captured symbol

and so on  ...
```

Comment: PLS, comment out what's wrong with this question and I will correct it, instead of down voting

Comment: Your arbitrary should match/should not match examples don’t make it clear what the underlying logic is supposed to be. Describe that. Plus, SO is not a “I want, you make” type of site. You need to show us your attempts.

Comment: Not sure that should be done using regex in the first place ... But if it has to, I’d probably start by ordering the characters of all those words alphabetically (via an additional column in your table), because creating a regex that covers all possible orders of those letters is not going to be fun. And then you create your regex using matching quantifiers - so for you initial example that contains the letter a once, that could be a simple `a?`, and for p that occurs twice, `p{0,2}` - match zero to two p characters, etc.

Comment: A lot of problems can be solved using a regex, but this is really not a regex problem.  You should rather try to make a method that counts the chars in the word and check that against the expected number of chars.  I must admit that it is an interesting problem

Comment: @CBroe it's interesting solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
\b(?!\w*([alertho])\w*\1)(?!\w*([p])(\w*\2){2})[aplertho]{5}\b
```

Details:

- `\b` - Word boundary (opening).
- `(?!\w*([alertho])\w*\1)` - Negative lookahead, test for more than 1
  occurrence of the mentioned chars):

  - some word chars (optional),
  - one of chars allowed to occur once (capturing groupp #1),
  - some word chars (optional),
  - the same char as captured by groupp #1.
- `(?!\w*([p])(\w*\2){2})` - Negative lookahead, test for occurrence more
  than 2 times.
  Like before, but this time:

  - the capturing group has No 2,
  - the set of chars allowed contains only *p*,
  - this lookahead "fires" if the char captured by groupp #2 occured
    **two** times thereafter.
- `[aplertho]{5}` - What we are looking for - any of the allowed chars,
  5 occurrences.
- `\b` - Word boundary (closing).

Comment: what if I have `a,p,p,l,e,r,t,h,o,o,g,g` and want to match `googl`?

Comment: it would be `\b(?!\w*([alerth])\w*\1)(?!\w*([p])(\w*\2){2})[aplertgho]{5}\b` ?

Comment: Make changes in three places:
1. Remove *o* from the 1st capturing group.
2. Add  *g* and *o* to the 2nd capturing group.
3. Change the numer of chars to match, e.g. to `{5,6}` (*google* has 6 chars).

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not a regex solution to the problem, but sometimes regex isn't the solution.

```
public class WordChecker
{
    public WordChecker(params char[] letters)
    {
        Counters = letters.GroupBy(c => c).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => new Counter(g.Count()));
    }
    public WordChecker(string letters) : this(letters.ToArray())
    {
    }

    public bool CheckWord(string word)
    {
        Initialize();
        foreach (var c in word)
        {
            Counter counter;
            if (!Counters.TryGetValue(c, out counter)) return false;
            if (!counter.Add()) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        foreach (var counter in Counters)
            counter.Value.Initialize();
    }
    private Dictionary<char, Counter> Counters;
    private class Counter
    {
        public Counter(int maxCount)
        {
            MaxCount = maxCount;
            Count = 0;
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
            Count = 0;
        }
        public bool Add()
        {
            Count++;
            return Count <= MaxCount;
        }
        public int MaxCount { get; private set; }
        public int Count { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

And the way to use it is like this:

```
    WordChecker checker = new WordChecker("applertho");
    List<string> words = new List<string>(){"apple", "giraf", "earth", "hello"};
    foreach (var word in words)
        if (checker.CheckWord(word))
        {
            // The word is valid!
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Casperah :)  issue is that I don't want to modify source code which already exists (and it is written in node.js ).   Existing source code gives ability to search words in db using regex , so I only wanted corresponding regex statement